# Content delivery criteria for getting data from LinkInfo Table

Tags: tridion

I need to fetch component ids from link info table based where url field matches a certain value. Is there any criteria to get data from link_info table in tridion using content delivery api.
for example

Regards,
Rajendra

Comment: By Criteria i mean Criteria class in Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.Query through which i can execute query on broker database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Components don't have URLs, so that might be a bit tricky to achieve.

Pages do have URLs, and you can use the `PageFactory` class to find them, something along these lines:

```java
PageMetaFactory factory = new PageMetaFactory(publicationId);
PageMeta meta = factory.getMetaByUrl(publicationId, "/my/url");
List<ComponentPresentationMeta> cpMetas = meta.getComponentPresentationMetas();
```

This will contain a list of all component presentations for a given page. You can use `cpMeta.getComponentId()` to get the component ID of the component presentation in question.

You may want to start asking Tridion questions here: http://tridion.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, but the question is that i have a query in sql which i need to convert into broker api method. the query is                                                          select distinct component_id from dbo.link_info link where link.publication_id = 80 and link.url not like '%/Alumni%'. so now i want to know if there is any criteria which can return component id based on this condition using content delivery api.

Comment: I would check the documentation then - I'm not sure if there's any criteria related to URLs.